# 2 out of 3 ssh connections are reset and disconnects immediately

Tags: linux, ssh

I've having an issue where 2 out of 3 ssh connections are reset and disconnects immediately.  what could be wrong?  I would like to solve it without a reboot.
I have raised the maximum number of open files and it didn't help

```
ulimit -n
65535
```

Comment: Rate limiting, limit to number of concurrent connections per ip, solar flares, rodents eating away on your cables, BOFH network administrator, to name a few. Try to diagnose client side by increasing the verbosity of the ssh command and by logging on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Try invoking ssh with `-v` or `-vv` or even `-vvv`to increase the amount of debug messages printed to stdout, and then use that information to help determine the issue.

Hope this helps!